# maximum intensity projection matlab with color

Tags: matlab, image-processing, particles

Hi all I have a stack of images of fluorescent labeled particles that are moving through time. The imagestack is gray scaled.

I computed a maximum intensity projection by taking the maximum of the image stack in the 3rd dimension.

```
Example:
ImageStack(x,y,N) where N = 31 image frames.

2DProjection = max(ImageStack,[],3)
```

Now, since the 2D projection image is black and white, I was hoping to assign a color gradient so that I can get a sense of the flow of particles through time. Is there a way that I can overlay this image with color, so that I will know where a particle started, and where it ended up?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by color gradient? Do you want to set the color bar based on pixel intensity in 2DProjection? And why colormap(jet), or colormap(hot) won't work for your case? Thanks

Comment: No, the color would denote time. So blue would be frame 1 (first time point), and red would be frame 31 (last time point). The 2D projection becomes the track that the particle follows. I am trying to visualize, using color, the starting, and end position of a particle.

Comment: The point is basically to get a sense of flow of the particles as they move through time. Whether the best way to do this is by overlaying color, I am not sure. But I thought it could be a first start. Definitely open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the second output of `max` to get which frame the particular maximum came from. `max` returns an index matrix which indicates the index of each maximal value, which in your case will be the particular frame in which it occurred. If you use this with the `imagesc` function, you will be able to plot how the particles move with time. For instance:

```
ImageStack(x,y,N) where N = 31 image frames.

[2DProjection,FrameInfo] = max(ImageStack,[],3);
imagesc(FrameInfo);
set(gca,'ydir','normal'); % Otherwise the y-axis would be flipped
```

Comment: This was a really slick, and quick solution. Thanks very much for this. It doesn't look all that bad either. If you have any other ideas for an analysis like this, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum up bright pixels of each image with one another after coloring each image. This way you will have mixed colors on overlapped areas which you will miss using max function. Although I like the previous answer more than mine.

```
hStep = 1/N;
currentH = 0;
resultImage = uint8(zeros(x,y,3));
for i = 1 : N
   rgbColor = hsv2rgb(currentH,1,0.5);
   resultImage(:,:,1) = resultImage(:,:,1) + im(:,:,i) * rgbColor(1);
   resultImage(:,:,2) = resultImage(:,:,2) + im(:,:,i) * rgbColor(2);
   resultImage(:,:,3) = resultImage(:,:,3) + im(:,:,i) * rgbColor(3);
   currentH = currentH + hStep;
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this I learned some new things with your code. As I told the previous poster, if you have any other ideas for a flow analysis like this, I'd love to hear it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your attempt in improving my answer to another question, though it was rejected by the moderators, probably they thought it is better suit as a comment. +1 for your answer here. Thanks